# Animate :target element on target event in CSS3

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I am building a lightbox based on the CSS3 selector `:target` which selects an element based on the hash in the url. I want to animate the target element on the `:target` event, but this doesn't seem to work.

Let's say we have a div `#banana which` is shown when a link to `#banana` is pressed.

```
#banana {display: none;}
#banana:target {display: block;}
```

This works fine. But when trying to animate the element, that doesn't work. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/uo0khafg/).

```
div#banana {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 5s linear 1s;
}

div#banana:target {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The element won't fade in. It is as if the browser skips the animation and immediately triggers the end result.

Comment: remove the display properties wich cannot be animated. display state swithc from a state to another. opacity is fine from 0.00 to 1.00 there is many steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the `display` property. The `display` property can't be transitioned since you can't really animate an element turning from nothing into a block.

The `display` property can be left out altogether. You will however need to give your element `visibility: hidden` so that it will not prevent the link from being clicked, then transition it to `visibility: visible`:

```css
div#banana {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 5s linear 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
}

div#banana:target {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/uo0khafg/5)

Comment: D'oh, silly mistake! Is there any noticeable difference between using `visiblity` and a negative `z-index`?

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: I realized you were implementing a lightbox - presumably the div needs to overlay the rest of the page to focus on the lightbox item. Having a negative z-index would defeat that purpose.

Comment: Considering that a `z-index` is numeric and can be animated, can't I simply animate it together with the opacity from `-1` to `1000`?

Comment: Actually, you probably could. I've never transitioned `z-index` before, so I can't comment further.

Comment: Just a confirmation: `visiblity` as well as animating `z-index` work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to animate display property. There is simply no gradual stages between `none` and `block`.

In your case you can "hide" element by using huge negative top position and revert it back to `0` on target event. Actual transition will be handled by changing opacity.

```css
div#banana {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: -1000px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

div#banana:target {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="banana">
    <a href="#">close</a>
</div>
<a href="#banana">Do you want a banana? Click me!</a>
```